# Novice Salesforce User - How can I create a time stamp in a field when another field is filled in

Tags: community, datetime

I have a salesforce (QUIP) spreadsheet that people fill out when someone checks in. There are 5 fields. The first one is their Amazon log in(A2-A200). I want the last field that I created (G1-G200) to give a date/time timestamp when the Amazon log in field is filled in with a value. I am having problems building a formula to perform that action.

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: So just to clarify, you are looking to fill dateTime in the field (G1-G200)?
Could you please provide more context on what these field types are?
Also, what is the current formula that you have built for this?